# Notice: Array to string conversion in token_replace() (line 102 of /var/www/html/includes/token.inc)

Tags: tokens

I am getting this notice when adding a content type in Drupal 7.24.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in token_replace() (line 102 of /var/www/html/includes/token.inc)

What does it mean? Could I reinstall the modules to fix it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a third-party module.

Comment: In short: It means a module is using not correct code and that should be changed; re-installing modules would not help, since that error is caused by code used by the Token module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Notice: Array to string conversion in token_replace() (line 102 of /.../includes/token.inc).](https://drupal.org/node/1649458)

> This is a dirty fix that excludes wrong values passed into the
>   token_replace(). Use it only as a last resort, this does not solve the
>   issue but only disables the message !
>
> Open token.inc and change the content of `token_replace()`
>
> ```
> return str_replace($tokens, $values, $text);
> ```
>
> Change to:
>
> ```
>  foreach ($replacements as $value => $replacement) {
>    if ((!is_array($value)) && (!is_array($replacement))&& (!is_array($text))) {
>      $text = str_replace($value, $replacement, $text);
>    }
>  }  
>  return $text;
> ```

Comment: actually it has gone away from deleting a field